# How to add options to the appmenu in Gnome Shell

Tags: gnome, appmenu, minimize

It is possible to add "Minimize" and "Resize window" in the menu next to the activities button? Is there an app/extension for that? Or is it possible by editing a document?

Now only show the close option and would be really useful to add this options.

Answer (score 0):

Add the extension (with [gnome-tweak-tool [image: software_center_icon]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-tweak-tool) )after adding this repository.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extension-window-buttons
```

Comment: Kind of, but I mean that when I click on the app indicator I only get the close application, and I want to add the minimize and resize options. For instance Firefox. I click in the firefox logo on the top panel and only says close firefox.

Comment: This is the menu that I mean http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/9935/menuus.png